# Cypher query which returns the students born in a certain year

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my Neo4j database a have nodes, labeled as students. Student nodes have such a property as *date_of_birth*, which is of type *date*(for example: *date_of_birth:"1997-01-01"*). I want to return all the students who where born in the year "1997" for example.

I tried to do sth like this:

```
match (n:Student) 
with n.date_of_birth as d 
where d.year="1997"
return n
```

But I am getting this error:
 Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Variable `n` not defined ("return n"^)

Why `n` is not defined in this query and how should I change the query to get the result I need?

Comment: Does `match (n:Student) where n.date_of_birth.year = "1997" return n` do it (ie... removing the `with`...

Comment: Otherwise, you need to  include `n` in the `with`... eg: `match (n:Student) with n, n.date_of_birth as d where d.year="1997" return n`...

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions and in both I get no result at all

Comment: try `d.year=1997` without quotes then... it might well be a numeric...?

Comment: Now I am getting the expected result. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great to hear... I've made that an answer... it might come in useful for others later

Comment: You might also be able to (I don't have a neo instance/data handy to check) also use `match (n:Student {date_of_birth.year: 1997}) return n` here... can't remember if cypher supports nested attribute access though...

Comment: I think cypher doesn't support nested attribute, because such a query would return an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two things:

1) The `WITH` statement only carries forward explicitly what you tell it, so if you want `n` to be usable in a `RETURN` you need to include `n`

2) The `.year` of a `date` is numeric, so you need to compare it to a numeric and not a string , so `1997` instead of `"1997"`

This'll make the query:

```
MATCH (n:Student)
WITH n, n.date_of_birth as d
WHERE d.year == 1997
RETURN n
```